# Looping function for a non delimited block of code in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to copy-cat/build up/import a function that works like a while loop with a wait/delay/sleep function at the end, like this:

```
0:   while (true) do
1:     codeline1
2:     codeline2
3toN:   ...
N:     codelineN
N+1:   wait(min,max) 
N+2: end
```

But using a single line for the while statment, like this:

```
0: auto(min,max)
1: codeline1
2: codeline2
3toN: ...
N: codelineN
```

If we find more than 1 auto() line, we have to loop until the next auto() line, or the end of the code:

```
 0:     auto(min1,max1)
 1:     codeline1
 2:     codeline2
 3to17:  ...
 17:    codeline17
 18:    auto(min2,max2)
 19:    codeline19
 20:    codeline20
 21toN:  ...
 N:     codelineN
```

Note that its not using "do" or "end".
I have no clue on how its made, googled a lot, but still didn't figure out how to get the code blocks to execute below the "auto()" lines, and iterate through them.
Any ideas?

**PS**:

All the apps i've used this code within, were using another framework as c# or c++ as the main engine, in which you could play/stop the lua scripts, if they were just not a loop, it would be executed just once.

It could be a framework function, prior to the lua processing (a simple syntax reader to detect auto statments, plus acting accordingly).

What I'm asking here is:

Is it possible to make a function in lua like that?
Is there a library or something like that to perform that kind of loops?

Comment: I don't understand how could you have two `auto` blocks.  According to your description, first `auto` block will act as infinite loop, and second `auto` block will never be executed.  How would you exit from the first infinite loop?  Lua syntax does not allow to use `break` statement outside loop statement (repeat/for/while).

Comment: Well, i've added more information to the question right now.
I dont know how it was done. I dont know if its possible with Lua itself, to be honest, but maybe someone here can give me a clue or confirm if it was a framework function.
Maybe there's a library which makes this sort of stuff, but for now im out of ideas.

Comment: The thing you are looking for is in whatever calls the script; `auto` can be anything, even an empty function as long as it's parsed beforehand by caller. Of course it could also do something like yield `min` and `max` to the caller. It doesn't really matter. Yes, you can implement it in Lua. I didn't use library that executes such weirdly looped scripts, but since you are trying to mimic something existing then there should be one. Try implementing it and then come back if you have problems.

Comment: So definitely there should be a framework (caller) function behind it, prior to the lua execution, so lua doesn't even read that line of code :P
Thanks for help!

Comment: Don't assume either. `auto` may be an actual lua function. Just do whatever will work for you. E.g. you could implement it with tricky use of coroutines and yield in `auto` without really parsing the script at all.

Comment: I haven't enough lua skills to make such a function in Lua at moment, but I'll get to make it. Meanwhile i've done a ez caller function which detects auto statments, stores their location, and then split the code into pieces and execute them in separate tasks but using the same trigger to stop the loop across all of them. Also handles code before any `auto` statment prior to the loops execution.